# Django form saying "this field is required" (even text fields) although it's been filled

Tags: python, django

A few other people have had this problem before but they were all file-related. For me, even text fields that I have filled (and must be filled) return "This Field is Required" error whilst I have done everything people suggested. Have a look at my code:

**Views**

```
class MainForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    subject = forms.CharField()
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    file = forms.FileField()
    password = forms.CharField()

def mainpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MainForm(request.FILES or None, request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse('Ok')


    else:
        form = MainForm()
    return render(request, "main.html", {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(file):
    name = file.name

    with open(os.path.join("static\img", "{0}".format(name)), 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

**Template:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ siteTitle }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
{% include 'header.html' %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </ul>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

It should be noted that when I set everything to non-required, it just returns an empty form.

Thanks for your generous help.

Comment: Welcome! Please make the example simpler, by [removing anything that is irrelevant to demonstrating the behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you want to show. Conversely, please show explicitly what behaviour we should expect when executing your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of arguments in your form is wrong - `request.POST` must come first:

```
# request.POST must come before request.FILES.
form = MainForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Also, you don't need the `or None`. `POST` and `FILES` are always present in the [request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects), even if they are empty.

You probably also don't want those `ul` tags in the table:

```
<table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
</table>
```